# White space in onclick value causes incorrect HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using below JavaScript code to append `<tr>` row to `<table>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addRow() {
        var filesName = 'Document Draft.png'
        var newRow = "<tr><td>td Data 1</td><td><a onclick=deleteDocument(this,'" + filesName + "')>Delete</a></td></tr>";
        $("#idDocList").append(newRow);
    } 
</script>
```

This code adds one `tr` to `table`.

**Problem:** But the issue is that `filesName` has one **white space** which is wrongly render on DOM as below:

```
<tr>
    <td>td Data 1</td>
    <td>
        <a onclick="deleteDocument(this,'Document" Draft.png')"">Delete</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

So the `onclick` doesn't work because rendered HTML is

```
onclick="deleteDocument(this,'Document" Draft.png')
```

As you can see in above line, it will take **( " )** instead of white space. How to fix it?

Comment: Try using ''(2 single quotes) where you have '.

Comment: Use `...<a onclick=\"deleteDocument(this,'" + filesName + "')\">...` or better forget about outdated inline JS `onclick=""` and use normal event handlers...

Comment: URL Encode the file name:
`var newRow = "<tr><td>td Data 1</td><td><a onclick=deleteDocument(this,'" + encodeURIComponent(filesName) + "')>Delete</a></td></tr>";`

Comment: You are using jQuery then, Why are you using ugly inline click handler?

Comment: This is the wrong way to do it. You should add a class to the `td`s, then use an event listener on the `#idDocList`. Something like `$('#idDocList').on('click', '.tdclass', function(){...})`

Comment: @Tom - am looking for `onclick="deleteDocument(this, 'Document Draft.png')">`

Comment: @Regent - Thanks it works perfect .... I just have to add ("\") at the end and at the start. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have spaces in `onclick` property value, you should wrap its value with, for example, `""`:

```
...<a onclick=\"deleteDocument(this,'" + filesName + "')\">...
```

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/anLt67aL/).

Instead of inline JS `onclick=""` (which is discouraged nowdays), you can use jQuery's `.on("click")`:

```
var filesName = 'Document Draft.png';
var newRow = "<tr><td>td Data 1</td><td><a class='delete'>Delete</a></td></tr>";
$("#idDocList").append(newRow);

$('#idDocList').on('click', ".delete", function()
{
    deleteDocument(this, filesName);
});
```

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/anLt67aL/1/).

Comment: @Prog you're welcome. Try "normal" event handlers when you have a time - they really make code looks better and prevent this kind of errors :)